# Error al subir un app al IONIC Package con plataforma IOs

Tags: ios, ionic, programación-móvil

Tengo un desarrollo realizado con **IONIC 1** que **funciona perfectamente en Android**. Estoy intentando subirlo a la nube con "**IONIC Package**" para plataforma **IOs**, para obtener el ejecutable ".**ipa**" de iPhone.

Con la ejecucion de "**ionic package build ios --profile MYSECURITYTAG**" en el CMD de Windows se sube al Package de IONIC Package, pero en estado **FAILED**.

Para conocer los detalles del error, ejecuto en CMD "**ionic package info NUMEROBUILD**" y visualizo lo siguiente:

> Caught exception:
>    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at Request._callback (C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\lib\package.js:116:27)
>       at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:373:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:1318:14)
>       at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\Alan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js:1266:12)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)

No he modificado mi **package.json** porque no se como debo configurarlo para plataforma IOs, sin embargo, no se si ese es el error

Estoy realizando todo desde una PC con Windows 10, desarrollando con IONIC 1.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El **package.json** lo modifican los comandos del cli de ionic cuando haces operaciones como añadir plataformas o plugins.
Te paso un package.json de una de mis apps para que compruebes que la estructura es igual, pueden variar los números de las versiones pero la estructura deberia ser identica.

```
{
"name": "app",
"version": "0.0.1",
"description": "An Ionic project",
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp": "1.1.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1": "2.1.1",
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "ionic": "3.8.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
},
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android",
        "ios"
    ]
}
}
```

Edito: Si el ionic-cli no esta actualizado suele dar problemas al usar el package

Comment: Dices que la "estructura es igual".. Es igual a que cosa @J0se?

Comment: Al fichero que te he puesto ahi arriba... mira que tenga todos los nodos y que esten bien cerrados los {, tambien prueba a tener actualizado la version del ionic-cli